# Typo correction in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and I love it!
One thing I miss though, is the suggestions to correct typos of fields and the like.

For example:

```
int myfield = 5;
myField++;
```

This would give me a lightbulb quick fix to *Change to 'myfield'*.

In IntelliJ, the closest I've come to this functionality is the *Rename Refererence* suggestion, which isn't quite as quick, especially in classes with many other fields.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ 13.x, go to Settings > IDE Settings > Editor > Code Completion. Make sure Autopopup Code Completion is checked. This will auto suggest *myfield* when you start typing *myField*, and you can select with cntl-space (or the mouse).

It will even correct it automatically if you just type a space in myField if you have *Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc*. checked. Also check out *Auto-insert when only one choice*

[IntelliJ settings docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html)

Comment: That's nice to know. It would be nice for a suggestion to fix the typo if I've already typed it, and my cursor is elsewhere, as in Eclipse. Thanks though!

Comment: Down voters, it would be helpful if you could give me a clue why you're down voting the answer. Otherwise I can't improve future answers. Thanks!